# CSS Sprites loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the src attribute of img inside of my span with id="slider_arrow",

```
<span id="slider_arrow">
      <img />
</span>
```

each time my jquery function runs:

```
    $("#0").click(function () {
           /*Rest of the function*/
        var arrow = document.getElementById('slider_arrow');
        /*I want to add different slider_arrow's sprite each time i call this                           function*/            
    });
```

CSS:

```
.red_arrow_sprite{
    width:25px;
    height:12px;
    background:url("/Images/arrows.png") 0 0px;
}

.yellow_arrow_sprite{
    width:25px;
    height:12px;
    background:url("/Images/arrows.png") -26px 0px;
}

.black_arrow_sprite{
    width:25px;
    height:12px;
    background:url("/Images/arrows.png") -51px 0px;
}
```

My CSS Sprite file has 75px width and 12px of height. Each picture has 25px/12px.
The questions are:
1) Do I have correctly written CSS rules?

2) What I need to use to change src of img inside of span?

Thanks!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtkppwuc/3/

Comment: I can post some code to change the src attribute of your img, but are you sure that's what you need? Because that's not a sprite at all. And if that's what you want, I don't understand what's the point of all your css. A CSS background image is NOT the same thing as the src attribute of an image.

Comment: I understand, thanks :) I thought it will have the same effect:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the image inside `span` and use jQuery for setting the css class to your Slider, try this code

```
<span id="slider_arrow" class="red_arrow_sprite">         
</span>

$("#0").click(function () {
    var item = $('#slider_arrow');
    if (item.hasClass('red_arrow_sprite')){
       item.removeClass('red_arrow_sprite').addClass('yellow_arrow_sprite');
    } else if (item.hasClass('yellow_arrow_sprite')){
       item.removeClass('yellow_arrow_sprite').addClass('black_arrow_sprite');
    } else {
       item.removeClass('black_arrow_sprite').addClass('red_arrow_sprite');           
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#0").click(function () {
    var classes = ['red_arrow_sprite','yellow_arrow_sprite','black_arrow_sprite'];
    var $span = $('#slider_arrow');
    $span.attr('class', (classes[($.inArray($span.attr('class'), classes)+1)%classes.length])); 
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vtkppwuc/6/

Comment: this.className should be replaced by $span.attr('class')

Comment: Your answer is a pretty nifty trick. I'll probably use it myself.